# What is the best method to store saved user accounts in a windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have been developing an app that uses Azure mobile services to store accounts and other information. I'm adding an option for users to save/remember the user account locally so that they don't have to type in their email and password every time. The application will be used in a business setting and multiple users will be able to save their account to the same device/computer for fast user switching much like how windows 8/8.1 has multiple user accounts setup. I will need a local storage or database to save the accounts to. it will be storing encrypted passwords and they will also have the option to add a pin to the saved account. I have looked into sqlite which i am familiar with but is there a better method for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Sqlite would be prudent if you have some tens of users as it would be a lot easier to manage. If you only expect to have 2-10 you might want to try to just store these in a file and protect like so

```
private static async Task<string> ProtectAsync(string data)
{
  var clearBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(data, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
  var provider = new DataProtectionProvider(Scope); // Scope being machine or user
  var encryptedBuffer = await provider.ProtectAsync(clearBuffer);
  return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptedBuffer);
}
```

Comment: I'll keep that option in mind. I was also looking at the [password vault class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx)